# Como poner un texto e imagen como encabezado en documento PDF de Itextsharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Hola a todos estoy trabajando con *Itextsharp* y en el documento pdf que ya realize quiero agregarle como encabezado un titulo y al lado una imagen de la empresa pero no sale como yo quiero esto es lo que hize pero no funciona:

```
Paragraph title = new Paragraph(string.Format("RAYO DE LUZ"), new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 20, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
           title.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
           doc.Add(title);

           byte[] bytesImagen = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter().ConvertTo(Resources.nplk, typeof(byte[])) as byte[];
           iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytesImagen);
           imagen.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
           imagen.ScaleAbsolute(120f, 120f);
           doc.Add(imagen);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿No te coloca ni título ni imagen? Revisa esto: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/add-image-in-pdf-using-itextsharp1 te puede ayudar en algo ;)

Comment: mm si agrega el titulo pero la imagen la coloca abajo y yo la quiero que vaya al lado del titulo como encabezado

Comment: si comentas o quitas (solo por un momento)   doc.Add(title); y dejas el resto tal cual, te sigue agregando la imagen abajo?

Comment: am solo aparece la imagen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tienes que ir jugando con las posiciones de la imagen, en base al plano cartesiano:

Iniciando en la posición `x=0, y=0` (esquina inferior izquierda de la página)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te anexo las líneas de código del ejemplo:

```
//OBTENGO LA IMAGEN desde archivo
    public static iTextSharp.text.Image img = Image.GetInstance("Logo.png");
    private void CrearPDFConImagen()
    {
        try
        {
            Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);//Horizontal
            //Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc
                , new System.IO.FileStream(
                    System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
                    + "\\EjemploImagen" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf",
                    System.IO.FileMode.Create));

            Doc.Open();                

            // Le colocamos el título y el autor
            // **Nota: Esto no será visible en el documento
            Doc.AddTitle("Reporte de ejemplo Con imagen");
            Doc.AddCreator("Cristina Carrasco - cristina.carrasco.angulo@gmail.com");

            //var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("Logo.png");
            var parrafo2 = new Paragraph("             Titulo del PDF");
            parrafo2.SpacingBefore = 200;
            parrafo2.SpacingAfter = 0;
            parrafo2.Alignment = 1; //0-Left, 1 middle,2 Right
            Doc.Add(parrafo2);
            Doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            img.ScaleToFit(125f, 60F);

            //Imagen - Esquina inferior izquierda
            img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            Doc.Add(img);

            //Imagen  - Movio en el eje de las X
            img.SetAbsolutePosition(200, 0);
            Doc.Add(img);

            //Imagen - Movio en el eje de las Y
            img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 200);
            Doc.Add(img);

            //Imagen - Movio en el eje de las Y
            img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 750);
            Doc.Add(img);

            //Imagen - Movio en el eje de las Y
            //Esta imagen es la que esta centrada a un lado del titulo
            img.SetAbsolutePosition(150, 750);
            Doc.Add(img);

            Doc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);
        }
    }
```

En esta línea:

```
var parrafo2 = new Paragraph("             Titulo del PDF");
```

Agregue algunos espacios al inicio para que la imagen se vea mas o menos centrada.

Espero que te sea de utilidad, saludos.

**Actualizaciones:**

Anexo código fuente: [Click para descargar](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1NrUmB-KIz6cXJlbXVtVU5hM0k)

**2016-Ene-10**

Te explico mas a detalle.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión del `itextsharp` que uso es la 5.5.10.0, tendrías que validar eso.

Agrego las referencias en el archivo como se muestra en el recuadro verde.

Y al crear la variable `img`, lo que hago es crear una instancia de `iTextSharp.text.mage` y le mando el nombre del archivo `Logo.png` al constructor, el cual debe estar agregado al proyecto, como se muestra en el recuadro rojo de la imagen anterior.

Otra cosa importante de la imagen es que debe existir en la carpeta de la aplicación para eso yo hice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccione la opción `Copy to Output Directory = Copy always` en el cuadro de propiedades (clic derecho en el archivo `Logo.png` y después clic en la opción `propiedades` del menú contextual en la sección `Explorador de soluciones` del `Visual Studio`), puedes hacer esto o copiar el archivo directamente a la carpeta donde corre la aplicación.

Esta es la imagen que tengo agregada al proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar la aplicación se copia a la carpeta del `.exe` (en mi caso es un aplicación de Windows):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal vez ese es el detalle que te hace falta.  Cuando la imagen no existe, el sistema lo busco y marca error (*No se puede encontrar el archivo*):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Cristina am me apoye en cada una de las respuestas de cada uno y ya me agrega la imagen pero aun no queda como quiero

Comment: lo que haces es que no llega bn al margen de la orilla de la derecha

Comment: Puedes ajustar el tamaño de la imagen, revisar que no tenga bordes, con algún programa como paint.net, y después en código utilizar la función: `img.ScaleToFit(125f, 60F);` para ajustar el tamaño, con el código de la respuesta puedes moverlo en el plano cartesiano hasta que quede como lo deseas, principalmente revisa que este ajustada la imagen, tal vez tiene mucho borde blanco y queda encima de todo.

Comment: ya revise y lo puse tal cual tu lo pones pero no hace nada

Comment: Esa parece una respuesta de un usuario final y no de un programador... ¿Qué significa no hace nada?, te voy a compartir el proyecto y allí lo revisas en programación, puede ser que tu imagen la que no esta bien diseñada o recortada, o tal vez estas insertando otro objeto encima.  Tendría que ver tu código para ayudarte.  Mientras publico mi ejemplo y lo revisas.

Comment: Si tienes razon perdon es que me estrese am estube investigando otras cosas deja voy a probar y checar tu ejemplo y te comento que sucedio vale

Comment: Ok, si tienes mas información sobre porque no puedes imprimir el logo, hazlo saber por favor.

Comment: oye tengo un problema en la parte que tu pones `public static iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("Logo.png");` a la hora de ejecutarlo me marca error me podrias explicar como funciona exactamente esta linea de codigo

Comment: ¿Qué error te marca la excepción?

Comment: ya ninguno mil gracias me ayudo para agregar la imagen

Answer (score 2):

***Disculpa por los posibles errores; no trabajo con C# así que no estoy 100% seguro de la sintaxis; espero que esté claro.***

De esta forma puedes incluir un encabezado y/o pie de página al comienzo/fin de cada página:

Dentro de tu código, agrega esta clase (en mi caso, agregué una tabla que contiene una imagen; puedes modificar la tabla para tener dos celdas lado a lado, o como mejor te acomode):

```
public class itsEvents : PdfPageEventHelper {

    /*Evento que ocurre al iniciar una nueva página en el documento. Se utiliza para insertar el encabezado.*/
    public override void OnStartPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
    {
        PdfPTable t;
        PdfPCell c;

        Image imgLogo;
        String rutaLogo = Server.MapPath("../logo.png");

        imgLogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(rutaLogo);

        t = new PdfPTable(1);
        t.WidthPercentage = 100;

        float[] w = new float[1];
        w[0] = 10;
        t.SetWidths(w);

        c = new PdfPCell(imgLogo);
        c.Border = 0;
        c.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
        c.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        t.AddCell(c);

        document.Add(t);
    }

    /*Evento que ocurre antes de pasar a una nueva página en el documento. Se utiliza para insertar el pie de página.*/
    public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
    {
    }

}
```

Y en tu clase principal, cuando creas el documento:

```
PdfWriter pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(ruta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
itsEvents ev = new itsEvents();
pdfWrite.PageEvent = ev;
```

Si necesitas poner un encabezado sólo en ciertas páginas, dentro de los eventos `OnStartPage` y `OnEndPage` obtienes el número de página de la siguiente forma:

```
int pageN = writer.PageNumber;

if (pageN == 1) {
    // Encabezado/pie de página sólo en la primera página
}
```

Comment: ok deja voy a checarlo vale

Comment: ey mil gracias parte de tu sintaxis me ayudo

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
   string archivoImagen= "logo.jpg";
   string imagenPath= Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"img\", archivoImagen); 
// Esto es C:\MyProjects\Apps\TUApp\bin\Debug\img\logo.jpg




Image imagen = Image.GetInstance(imagenPath);  
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Add(new Chunk(imagen, 0, 0));
p.Add(new Phrase("Esto es un logo")); 
document.Add(p);
```

Comment: ok lo voy a intentar pero que va en (imagenPath)??

Comment: La url de tu imagen.

Comment: lo ejecuto y me marca error